# Python How to Implement Threading of my Email Class

Tags: python, python-multithreading, email-threading

I have a pretty large email class that constructs  & sends various emails with mime, attachments etc.

Everything works fine but it is called from my main loop and the sendmail method using smtplib can sometimes block for several seconds because of issues at the other end.

I want to run the code in a new thread so my main loop can keep trucking.

I have tried two approaches without success:

- Calling my class using a Thread
- Inherit my  V1 class from Thread

Neither stop the blocking. Below is a working skeleton of my class (V1) and what I have tried. Success would be to see "Done" appear immediately after "Starting" instead of waiting the 3 seconds for sendmail to finish.
Hoping there is an easy way to do this...

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

class EMailv1():
    def __init__(self):
        self._from_address = 'a@b.com'
        self._to_addresslist = []

    def buildmessage(self, **kwargs):
        message ={}
        return message

    @staticmethod
    def sendmail(message):
        sleep(5)
        return

class EMailv2(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._from_address = 'a@b.com'
        self._to_addresslist = []

    def run(self):
        pass

    def buildmessage(self, **kwargs):
        message ={}
        return message

    @staticmethod
    def sendmail( message):
        sleep(3)
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Starting V1 class send in current manner, which blocks if smtplib cannot deliver mail')
    email =EMailv1()
    msg = email.buildmessage(a='a',b='b')
    email.sendmail(msg)
    print('v1 Done after sendmail sleep finishes')

    print('Starting  threaded call to send V1 class')
    email = EMailv1()
    msg = email.buildmessage(a='a',b='b')
    t = Thread(target=email.sendmail(msg))
    t.start()
    print('Threaded call of V1 Done after sendmail sleep finishes')

    print('Starting V2 class inheriting Thread')
    email = EMailv2()
    msg = email.buildmessage(a='a',b='b')
    email.start()
    email.sendmail(msg)
    print('V2 Done after sendmail sleep finishes')
```

Comment: What's the difference between ```EMailv1``` and ```Emailv2``` here, besides the ```Threading``` inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second version, instead of

```
t = Thread(target=email.sendmail(msg))
```

you should do

```
t = Thread(target=email.sendmail, args=[msg])
```

In the way you wrote, it is evaluating `email.sendmail(msg)` *before* constructing the thread, that's why you see that you wait 5 seconds before proceeding.

Instead you should pass the thread a target function and it's args separately, without evaluating them.

Here is a fixed and minimalized version:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

class EMailv1():
    def __init__(self):
        self._from_address = 'a@b.com'
        self._to_addresslist = []

    def buildmessage(self, **kwargs):
        message ={}
        return message

    @staticmethod
    def sendmail(message):
        sleep(5)
        print("Launched thread: I'm done sleeping!")
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Main thread: Starting  threaded call to send V1 class')
    email = EMailv1()
    msg = email.buildmessage(a='a', b='b')
    t = Thread(target=email.sendmail, args=[msg])
    t.start()
    print("Main thread: I have created the thread, and am done.")
```

Output:

```
Main thread: Starting  threaded call to send V1 class
Main thread: I have created the thread, and am done.
Launched thread: I'm done sleeping!
```

With that said, I'd also suggest you to take a look at some abstractions provided in Python for doing multithreaded work. For instance, take a look at features like [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) - these are usually preferable to working directly with `Thread`s.

Comment: Thanks  - that got me going and email no longer blocks. In the end I renamed sendmail to tsendmail and then added a new sendmail that just called and started tsen dmail per your code. That way I I did not have to change any calls to my email class.  I will look at ThreadPoolExecutor but Thread seems to be working  for now